# Python check exit status of a shell command

Tags: python, subprocess, exit-code

# function to run shell commands

```
def OSinfo(runthis):
        #Run the command in the OS
        osstdout = subprocess.Popen(runthis, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        #Grab the stdout
        theInfo = osstdout.stdout.read() #readline()
        #Remove the carriage return at the end of a 1 line result
        theInfo = str(theInfo).strip()
        #Return the result
        return theInfo
```

# flash raid firmware

```
OSinfo('MegaCli -adpfwflash -f ' + imagefile + ' -noverchk -a0')
```

# return status of the firmware flash

```
?
```

One resource recommended using 'subprocess.check_output()', however, I'm not sure how to incorporate this into function OSinfo().

Comment: do you just want to check that the return code is 0?

Comment: Yes. Check if it's zero, if not then exit 1.

Comment: so you don't care about any output, just a non 0 exit status?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `osstdout.stdout.read()` to get the `stdout` of the subprocess you can instead use [`osstout.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) This will block until the subprocess terminates. Once this is done the attribute `osstout.returncode` will be set containing the return code of the subprocess.

Your function could then be written as

```
def OSinfo(runthis):
    osstdout = subprocess.Popen(runthis, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)

    theInfo = osstdout.communicate()[0].strip()

    return (theInfo, osstout.returncode)
```

Comment: For Python 2.7 on Windows, it throws an exception: `ValueError: close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr`  :-(

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to `return 1` if there is a non-zero exit status use `check_call`, any non zero exit status will raise an error which we catch and `return 1` else `osstdout` will be `0`:

```
import subprocess
def OSinfo(runthis):
        try:
            osstdout = subprocess.check_call(runthis.split())
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            return 1
        return osstdout
```

You also don't need shell=True if you pass a list of args.